# How do I add special characters in the dialog in CKeditor and WYSISYG?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor 3.6.3 along with WYSIWYG for filtered HTML, and I am using the default special characters plugin that is already available.
I want to modify the pop-up dialog that opens up and add certain other special characters like alpha, beta, gamma, etc, but I do not seem to get it working in filtered HTML inline. If I change the plugin.js file to add these special characters, I cannot see them getting updated in the pop-up.

Can anyone advise on what I should do? My SQL server supports UTF-8 unicode, and so does the browser.

Comment: Could anyone find a solution to this problem or has any clues on what would work? Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks.